# How can I mimic the -u and -d flags of curl in Python?

Tags: python, authentication, curl, python-requests

I've basically this curl command which I use in order to retrieve and access token

```sh
curl -u "username:password" --silent \
     -d "grant_type=password&username=app_username&password=app_password&scope=id"  \
     https://example.com/oauth2/access_token
```

Now I'd like to do the same with Python. I've tried to use requests like this:

```py
import requests
data = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "username": app_username,
    "password": app_password,
    "scope": "id"
}

url = 'https://example.com/oauth2/access_token'
req = requests.post(url, data=data, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
```

but I'm getting a 400 error.

Any hint on how to use the -u and -d curl options in this case?

Comment: Since it's not readily apparent when comparing your curl command to your Python code: Are `app_username`, `app_password`, `username`, and `password` all variables?

Comment: sorry, yes, they are